# How can i do DropDownBox IndexChanged Event in Jsp page?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I m adding DropDown in jsp page.
and m trying to redirect a page exact after index change without any button click.
How can i add it to jsp page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      $('com').bind('change', function () {
          var value = $(this).val();
          if(value==1) window.location = "servlet1?id=1";
if(value==2)window.location = "servlet1?id=2";
return false;
});
});
</script>
<body>
<select id="com">
<option></option>
<option value="1">Link1</option>
<option value="2">Link2</option>
</select></body>
```

Not working, is anything missing , plz

When i change index then i want to redirect to corresponding link/page.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do it as follows,

```
$(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#ID_OF_select_ITEM').bind('change', function () {
          var value = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          window.location = someURL; // redirect based on the value
      return false;
      });
});
```

Comment: how can i bind it with select?

Comment: read the comment, it is already described, `ID_OF_select_ITEM` is the id of your select box

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('com').bind('change', function () {
          var value = $(this).val();
          if(value==1)
              window.location = "servlet1?id=1";
              if(value==2)
                  window.location = "servlet1?id=2";
      return false;
      });
});
</script>

<body>
<select id="com">
<option></option>
<option value="1">Link1</option>
<option value="2">Link2</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

Just use '#com' instead of 'com' probably it will work

if still not working then let us know we have alternative for this task